# can't get ruby-debug on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Can't get ruby-debug engaged for rails 3.0

1) when I do a "gem list ruby-debug"  I get:
$ gem list ruby-debug

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ruby-debug (0.10.3)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.3 mswin32)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.5)

2) when I run "rails server --debugger" I get:
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:132:in 
`resolve': Could not find gem 'ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.3.0)', required by 'ruby-
debug', in any of the sources (Bundler::VersionConflict)
        from c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.2/lib/bundler/resolve
r.rb:130:in`catch'

Seems like a contradiction... the list says I have 0.10.3...

Thanks...

Comment: not sure what you mean.  irb works, but if I try the debugger method in irb it fails.

Answer (score 0):

have you run `bundle install` from your app root?